# STM32 USB Host + HID Joystick

Tags: usb, stm32

Имеется плата на базе STM32F401CU, от DevEBox, она поддерживает USB Host, задача состоит в подключении к ней HID-устройства, в данном случае джойстика Gunfighter. Для решения шел по простому пути: CubeMX, USB_HOST библиотека, все на HAL, и если с мышью и клавиатурой все заводится сразу и, через коллбэк `USBH_HID_EventCallback`, можно отобразить данные с устройства. С джойстиком так просто это не работает, библиотека рапортует о том, что устройство не поддерживается, чтобы обойти это внес некоторые правки в библиотеку, ориентируясь на данные из USBlyzer:

1. usbh_conf.h

```
/*----------   -----------*/
#define USBH_MAX_NUM_ENDPOINTS      1U

/*----------   -----------*/
#define USBH_MAX_NUM_INTERFACES      1U
```

2. usbh_core.c

Здесь было закомментировано все, что касалось создания создания и изменения IN канала

```
  phost->gState = HOST_ENUMERATION;

  phost->Control.pipe_out = USBH_AllocPipe(phost, 0x00U);
  // phost->Control.pipe_in  = USBH_AllocPipe(phost, 0x80U);

  /* Open Control pipes */
  // USBH_OpenPipe(phost, phost->Control.pipe_in, 0x80U,
  //               phost->device.address, phost->device.speed,
  //               USBH_EP_CONTROL, (uint16_t)phost->Control.pipe_size);

  /* Open Control pipes */
  USBH_OpenPipe(phost, phost->Control.pipe_out, 0x00U,
                phost->device.address, phost->device.speed,
                USBH_EP_CONTROL, (uint16_t)phost->Control.pipe_size);
```

3. usbh_hid.h

Был добавлен define, чтобы, в дальнейшем, функция `USBH_HID_InterfaceInit` могла опознать джой

```
/* Interface Descriptor field values for HID Boot Protocol */
#define HID_BOOT_CODE                                 0x01U
#define HID_NONE_BOOT_CODE                            0x00U
#define HID_KEYBRD_BOOT_CODE                          0x01U
#define HID_MOUSE_BOOT_CODE                           0x02U
```

4. usbh_hid.c

Тут немного необязательностей, для вывода через SWO

```
  else if (phost->device.CfgDesc.Itf_Desc[interface].bInterfaceProtocol  == HID_NONE_BOOT_CODE)
  {
    USBH_UsrLog("Non boot device found!");
  }
```

Переключил протокол на Non-boot

```
case HID_REQ_SET_PROTOCOL:
    /* set protocol */
    classReqStatus = USBH_HID_SetProtocol(phost, 1U);
    if (classReqStatus == USBH_OK)
    {
      HID_Handle->ctl_state = HID_REQ_IDL
```

По итогу, последняя успешная точка в работе всего, что я наворотил – функция `USBH_HID_GetHIDReportDescriptor`, дескриптор приходит полным, без каких-либо проблем, но дальше проблемы начинаются. Когда доходит до `USBH_HID_GetReport`, находящейся в `USBH_HID_Process`, я получаю `USBH_NOT_SUPPORTED`, на чем, собственно, повествование и заканчивается. Дальше код крутится циклически в кейсе `HID_POLL` и никаких данных от джойстика мне не приходит.

Из интересных наблюдений могу отметить, что, в случае, если не производить изменения второго пункта, а в функции `USBH_HID_InterfaceInit` сделать вот так:

```
for (num = 0U; num < max_ep; num++)
  {
    if (phost->device.CfgDesc.Itf_Desc[interface].Ep_Desc[num].bEndpointAddress & 0x80U)
    {
      HID_Handle->InEp = (phost->device.CfgDesc.Itf_Desc[interface].Ep_Desc[num].bEndpointAddress);
      // HID_Handle->InPipe = USBH_AllocPipe(phost, HID_Handle->InEp);
      HID_Handle->InPipe = 1;

      /* Open pipe for IN endpoint */
      USBH_OpenPipe(phost, HID_Handle->InPipe, HID_Handle->InEp, phost->device.address,
                    phost->device.speed, USB_EP_TYPE_INTR, HID_Handle->length);

      USBH_LL_SetToggle(phost, HID_Handle->InPipe, 0U);
    }
```

то вместо дескриптора репорта, я получаю сам репорт, в надежде, что можно не мудрить дальше ничего, я решил зациклить это действие и просто получать нужную мне пачку данных из раза в раз этим запросом, однако, после второго получения все вешается в статус `USBH_BUSY`и данных у меня снова нет. Буду благодарен любым идеям и соображениям на этот счет, так же прикладываю данные по джою из USBlyzer:

```
Connection Status Device connected 
Current Configuration 1 
Speed Full (12 Mbit/s) 
Device Address 6 
Number Of Open Pipes 1 

Device Descriptor VKB-Sim Space Gunfighter L 
Offset Field Size Value Description 
0 bLength 1 12h  
1 bDescriptorType 1 01h Device 
2 bcdUSB 2 0200h USB Spec 2.0 
4 bDeviceClass 1 00h Class info in Ifc Descriptors 
5 bDeviceSubClass 1 00h  
6 bDeviceProtocol 1 00h  
7 bMaxPacketSize0 1 08h 8 bytes 
8 idVendor 2 231Dh  
10 idProduct 2 0127h  
12 bcdDevice 2 1997h 19.97 
14 iManufacturer 1 01h ". Alex Oz 2012-2020" 
15 iProduct 1 02h " VKB-Sim Space Gunfighter L " 
16 iSerialNumber 1 00h  
17 bNumConfigurations 1 01h  

Configuration Descriptor 1 Bus Powered, 500 mA
Offset Field Size Value Description 
0 bLength 1 09h  
1 bDescriptorType 1 02h Configuration 
2 wTotalLength 2 0022h  
4 bNumInterfaces 1 01h  
5 bConfigurationValue 1 01h  
6 iConfiguration 1 00h  
7 bmAttributes 1 80h Bus Powered 
 4..0: Reserved  ...00000   
 5: Remote Wakeup  ..0.....  No 
 6: Self Powered  .0......  No, Bus Powered 
 7: Reserved (set to one)
(bus-powered for 1.0)  1.......   
8 bMaxPower 1 FAh 500 mA 

Interface Descriptor 0/0 HID, 1 Endpoint
Offset Field Size Value Description 
0 bLength 1 09h  
1 bDescriptorType 1 04h Interface 
2 bInterfaceNumber 1 00h  
3 bAlternateSetting 1 00h  
4 bNumEndpoints 1 01h  
5 bInterfaceClass 1 03h HID 
6 bInterfaceSubClass 1 00h  
7 bInterfaceProtocol 1 00h  
8 iInterface 1 00h  

HID Descriptor 
Offset Field Size Value Description 
0 bLength 1 09h  
1 bDescriptorType 1 21h HID 
2 bcdHID 2 0111h 1.11 
4 bCountryCode 1 00h  
5 bNumDescriptors 1 01h  
6 bDescriptorType 1 22h Report 
7 wDescriptorLength 2 012Dh 301 bytes 

Endpoint Descriptor 81 1 In, Interrupt, 1 ms
Offset Field Size Value Description 
0 bLength 1 07h  
1 bDescriptorType 1 05h Endpoint 
2 bEndpointAddress 1 81h 1 In 
3 bmAttributes 1 03h Interrupt 
 1..0: Transfer Type  ......11  Interrupt 
 7..2: Reserved  000000..   
4 wMaxPacketSize 2 0040h 64 bytes 
6 bInterval 1 01h 1 ms 

Interface 0 HID Report Descriptor Joystick
Item Tag (Value) Raw Data 
Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
Usage (Joystick) 09 04  
Collection (Application) A1 01  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Report ID (1) 85 01  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (X) 09 30  
    Report Size (16) 75 10  
    Report Count (1) 95 01  
    Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
    Logical Maximum (4095) 26 FF 0F  
    Physical Maximum (4095) 46 FF 0F  
    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (Y) 09 31  
    Report Size (16) 75 10  
    Report Count (1) 95 01  
    Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
    Logical Maximum (4095) 26 FF 0F  
    Physical Maximum (4095) 46 FF 0F  
    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (Rx) 09 33  
    Report Size (16) 75 10  
    Report Count (1) 95 01  
    Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
    Logical Maximum (2047) 26 FF 07  
    Physical Maximum (2047) 46 FF 07  
    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (Ry) 09 34  
    Report Size (16) 75 10  
    Report Count (1) 95 01  
    Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
    Logical Maximum (2047) 26 FF 07  
    Physical Maximum (2047) 46 FF 07  
    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (Rz) 09 35  
    Report Size (16) 75 10  
    Report Count (1) 95 01  
    Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
    Logical Maximum (2047) 26 FF 07  
    Physical Maximum (2047) 46 FF 07  
    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
    Usage Page (Undefined) 05 00  
    Usage 09 00  
    Report Size (16) 75 10  
    Report Count (1) 95 01  
    Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
    Logical Maximum (2047) 26 FF 07  
    Physical Maximum (2047) 46 FF 07  
    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (Z) 09 32  
    Report Size (16) 75 10  
    Report Count (1) 95 01  
    Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
    Logical Maximum (2047) 26 FF 07  
    Physical Maximum (2047) 46 FF 07  
    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
    Usage Page (Undefined) 05 00  
    Usage 09 00  
    Report Size (16) 75 10  
    Report Count (1) 95 01  
    Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
    Logical Maximum (2047) 26 FF 07  
    Physical Maximum (2047) 46 FF 07  
    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
    Usage Page (Button) 05 09  
    Usage Minimum (Button 1) 19 01  
    Usage Maximum (Button 128) 2A 80 00  
    Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
    Logical Maximum (1) 25 01  
    Report Size (1) 75 01  
    Report Count (128) 96 80 00  
    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (Hat Switch) 09 39  
    Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
    Logical Maximum (7) 26 07 00  
    Physical Minimum (0) 35 00  
    Physical Maximum (360) 46 68 01  
    Unit (Eng Rot: Degree) 65 14  
    Unit Exponent (1) 55 01  
    Report Size (4) 75 04  
    Report Count (1) 95 01  
    Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,Null,Bit) 81 42  
    Usage (Undefined) 09 00  
    Unit (None) 65 00  
    Unit Exponent (0) 55 00  
    Report Size (4) 75 04  
    Report Count (3) 95 03  
    Input (Cnst,Ary,Abs) 81 01  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (Undefined) 09 00  
    Report Size (16) 75 10  
    Report Count (1) 95 01  
    Input (Cnst,Ary,Abs) 81 01  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (Undefined) 09 00  
    Report Size (16) 75 10  
    Report Count (1) 95 01  
    Input (Cnst,Ary,Abs) 81 01  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (Undefined) 09 00  
    Report Size (16) 75 10  
    Report Count (1) 95 01  
    Input (Cnst,Ary,Abs) 81 01  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (Undefined) 09 00  
    Report Size (8) 75 08  
    Report Count (23) 95 17  
    Input (Cnst,Ary,Abs) 81 01  
    Report ID (11) 85 0B  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (Undefined) 09 00  
    Report Size (8) 75 08  
    Report Count (63) 95 3F  
    Input (Cnst,Ary,Abs) 81 01  
    Report ID (8) 85 08  
    Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
    Usage (Undefined) 09 00  
    Report Size (8) 75 08  
    Report Count (63) 95 3F  
    Input (Cnst,Ary,Abs) 81 01  
    Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
    Logical Maximum (255) 26 FF 00  
    Physical Maximum (255) 46 FF 00  
    Report ID (88) 85 58  
    Report Size (8) 75 08  
    Report Count (63) 95 3F  
    Usage (Undefined) 09 00  
    Output (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,NVol,Bit) 91 02  
    Report ID (89) 85 59  
    Report Size (8) 75 08  
    Report Count (128) 95 80  
    Usage (Undefined) 09 00  
    Feature (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,NVol,Bit) B1 02  
End Collection C0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем-то, вопрос решился проще и большое кол-во действий были излишними, фактически, ошибкой было то, что я не верно описал инициализацию джойстика, точнее, сначала не написал вовсе и попытался использовать имеющуюся, от мышки. Однако, из-за разницы в размерности репорта происходило всё то, что происходило, установка буферов нужной размерности спасла ситуицию.

В решении помогла данная [статья](http://enjointhing.cn/?p=325)